# Сумма по столбцу в двумерном массиве с условием

Tags: python, массивы, суммирование

Есть двумерный массив

```
mas = [['пуб', 0.3, 0.4],
       ['нер', 0.5, 0.4],
       ['нер', 0.2, 0.1]]
```

Нужно просуммировать столбец 2 при условии, что первый элемент каждой строки равен 'нер' (то есть в результате должна быть сумма 0.5 + 0.2 = 0.7).

Написала такой расчет в цикле:

```
sum_num = 0
for m in mas:
    if m[0] == 'нер':
        sum_num += m[1]
```

Но хотелось бы такую задачу выполнить с использованием функции `sum()`

Comment: Переименовал `sum` в `sum_num`, т.к. `sum` это встроенная функция питона, и ее такой код переписывает, поэтому если после вашего кода вызвать, например `sum([1, 2])`, то будет ошибка, т.к. у переменной `sum` будет вызыван оператор `()`, что неприемлимо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В одну строку:

```
# Тут будет генератор
print(sum(row[1] for row in mas if row[0] == 'нер'))

# Тут будет создан новый список
print(sum([row[1] for row in mas if row[0] == 'нер']))
```

---

Подробнее:

```
rows = [row[1] for row in mas if row[0] == 'нер']
print(rows)  # [0.5, 0.2]
print(sum(rows))  # 0.7
```

---

Если использовать функциональную магию, тогда:

```
print(sum(map(lambda row: row[1], filter(lambda row: row[0] == 'нер', mas))))
```

Подробнее:

- `filter` оставит только строки с `'нер'`
- `map` применит лямбду к каждой строке и вернет второй элемент, сгенерировав коллекцию из вторых элементов каждого элемента
- `sum` суммирует все полученные элементы

Comment: А можно также в одну строку посчитать количество таких строк, где первый элемент 'нер'?

Comment: Для этого используйте функцию `len`: `print(len([row[1] for row in mas if row[0] == 'нер']))`